# Consuming a .net assembly using asp classic

Tags: c#, asp.net, com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing a .NET Assembly from classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520165/accessing-a-net-assembly-from-classic-asp)

We currently have a website that is written in asp classic.  In order to gradually migrate the site to ASP.Net we've decided to build a class library that contains functions that we wish to rewrite in C#.  The problem is we are having difficulty getting this to work on asp classic.

Following tutorials We've:

1. Wrote a sample class as listed below.
2. Strongly named our assembly using 'sn -k OurKeyName.key'
3. Registered our assembly in the GAC using 'gacutil /i OurAssembly.dll'
4. Registered our assembly with COM using 'regasm /tlb WireCare.dll'

Upon performing the above steps we receive the following error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/page.asp, line 2

800401f3
```

Below is the code for the .net class:

```
namespace CompanyName
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string DoTest()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

And the asp page:

```
<%
    Dim cart : Set cart = Server.CreateObject("CompanyName.Test")
%>
```

The development machines are running:

- Windows 7 Professional 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2010

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Referenced from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520165/accessing-a-net-assembly-from-classic-asp Is your .NET assembly set to be COM visible?

Answer (score 0):

It could be permissions related. Does the account ASP is running under have adequate permissions on the .net assembly?

A quick (AND TEMPORARY) test would be to add the account ASP is running under (e.g. IUSR_server-name or NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) to the administrator's group on the machine and see if things start working. If so then you need to track down the specific file that has inadequate permissions.