# Run hashids server-side

Tags: server-side, hashids

I'm trying to use hashids in javascript and ASP but I need it to run on server-side as some check with DB need to occur before loading the page. The examples/documentation on their site don't cover that.
Can anyone give an example on the library is added to my asp and how to call encode() and decode(). Keep getting error 500 and I have to say I have never tried to run server-side an external library like this.

BTW, a tip to help other people, if you want to have something similar to tinyurl (like http://[domain]/[optional_subdirectory]/[hashid]) and only a single file on IIS to do the decoding, I setup a custom 404 page that catches all urls within the server and variable QUERY_STRING holds that hash for decoding and further processing ;)

```
var hash = String("<%=Request.ServerVariables('QUERY_STRING')%>").split("/").pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Hashids server side and use ASP(.NET?) there is a .NET version of the library.

http://hashids.org/net/

With more examples here https://github.com/ullmark/hashids.net

**Edit**: I also encourage people to not follow your tip and use a 404 page as a catch all route. ASP.NET has multiple ways of setting up routing. Again, if you were talking about ASP Classic then...   I'm sorry ;-)

Comment: It is indeed ASP Classic :)

Comment: @Gulliver I guess, you should be able import the .net assembly in ASP Classic, there are multiple post about that on Stack Overflow. The library must be "COM accessible" and I don't remember if I did anything with that.. But let me know if it doesn't work and maybe I can have a look at releasing a new version with that included. [post i found...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520165/accessing-a-net-assembly-from-classic-asp)

Comment: Had to have a solution by today so I changed a bit my logic to avoid the use hashids. Sorry I didn't post a comment earlier to save you time. I only got back home now. Thank you Markus