Is it possible to use .net assemblies Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client & in Classic ASP Project
My project is a standalone Classic ASP Project.
I would need to establish connection to Oracle db to retrieve some data.
Is it possible to use .Net assembly Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client?
I have manually added the dll in another folder & want to load the dll in project.
Dim conn
Dim oConn
Dim dllPath

'Configure dll path
 Set dllPath = Server.MapPath("references/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.dll")

'Connection to oracle database
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection")

'Connection string
tpasdns="Username=;'' Password='';Data Source=''"

'Open db connection
oConn.Open tpasdns

I am getting VBScript runtime error and 'Object required ['F:\path']'

I don't think you can use it directly. The .NET assembly needs to be compiled with "COM Visible", that's not the case for ODP.NET Managed Driver. Either you use the ODP.NET Unmanaged driver (however, this requires an Oracle client to be installed) or your write your own COM Visible DLL which wraps the ODP.NET Managed Driver. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520165/accessing-a-net-assembly-from-classic-asp
